# In this python pygame code, am I updating atrribute for the rectangle object .midbottom?

Tags: python, pygame

So I am working through No Starch Presses' Python Crash Course 2e. I have finally made it to the part where you create the Alien Invasion game. I am understanding everything up until these specific two lines of code.

There is a class called alien Invasion that holds a screen rect that will be passed to this class in ai_game.

\\

import pygame

class Ship:
"""A class to manage the ship"""

```
def __init__(self, ai_game):
    """Initialize the ship and set its starting position"""
    self.screen = ai_game.screen
    self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

    #load the ship image and get its rect.
    self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    #Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen
    self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

def blitme(self):
    """Draw the ship at its current location"""
    self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

\
The two lines I am not understanding are below. What is happening under the surface? Of course I know what the author says they are doing but I'm trying to understand how its doing this and not just what it is doing, so I may understand the rules and logic and not just accept the rules and logic on face value.

\\

```
    self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

def blitme(self):
    """Draw the ship at its current location"""
    self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

\\

`self.rect` represents an object in memory that stores data about a rectangle object on the screen, correct? My main question is the `.midbottom` following self.rect a attribute of the rect object? So in the first statement is the `.midbottom` attribute being set to the `.midbottom` attribute of the screen rectangle? While I was learning python as well it says be careful about setting values equal to one another in this way because changing one might change the other as well after you see them equal. Moving on, so okay so if that's true, the ship objects `.midbottom` attrribute is being set to the screens `.midbottom` attribute, when the blit() method is called how does blit() know where to position the ship? I never told it where to postion the ship. Does the blitmethod have default behavior that set the ship to the only known postition? I have read that by default everything is postioned at (0,0) so if you supply the ship object with data it will automatically place the ship where the user lasts entered data.

Comment: Please read the documentation before you ask a question. See [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit).

Answer (score 2):

A *Rect* object has exactly 4 attributes `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`. However there are many virtual attributes. If you set a virtual attribute under the hood, the attributes `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` are changed.
See [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html):

> The Rect object has several virtual attributes which can be used to move and align the Rect:
>
> ```py
> x,y
> top, left, bottom, right
> topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
> midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
> center, centerx, centery
> size, width, height
> w,h
> ```
>
> All of these attributes can be assigned to:
>
> ```py
> rect1.right = 10
> rect2.center = (20,30)
> ```

The position is stored in the `rect` attribute. See [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit):

> Draws a source Surface onto this Surface. The draw can be positioned with the dest argument. The dest argument can either be a pair of coordinates representing the position of the upper left corner of the blit **or a Rect, where the upper left corner of the rectangle will be used as the position for the blit**.

---

First a `pygame.Rect` object is created with the size of the *Surface*:

> ```py
> self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
> ```

Then the (middle bottom) position of the rectangle is set.

> ```py
> self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
> ```

This instruction changes the *x* and *y* coordinates so that the middle bottom point of the rectangle is at the middle bottom point of the window. This instruction will perfectly align the rectangle at the bottom center of the window.

Finally, the *Surface* is drawn at the position which is stored in the *Rect*:

> ```py
> self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
> ```

Comment: Okay I think I am getting it, but it just seems like it would make more sense if the statement read like ' this is the postion of the rectanlge' its confusing to me how its written. But im still confused on why do we set the self.rect.midbottom attribute the same as the screens midbottom atrribute.

Comment: @needyPheonix When you set `midbottom`, the x and y coordinate is set in that way that the middle bottom of the rectangle is in the middle bottom of the window. This instruction will perfectly align the rectangle at the bottom center of the window. But I don't know why the author wants to do that.

Comment: yes okay making some sense, I have to read something several times and talk myself through it. You are being very helfpul, thank you. Okay i get the midbttom point, lets say I define another postional attribute for the rect_object after the middbttm attribute. how will blit know where to print the surface, will it print the surface the last known value for the x and y?

Comment: okay im think im understanding. im thinking about the problem wrong here.

Comment: @needyPheonix Man read the documentation. [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html). A _Rect_ object has exactly 4 attributes `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`. However there are many virtual attributes. When you set an virtual attribute under the hood the attributes `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` are changed. This means that when you set `midbottom`, actually `x` and `y` are changed with a special logic.

Comment: alright thank you for your time! i can figure this out on my own now with the clarity you have provided i think . thank you very much !